# How to get reason revert using web3.eth.call

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, revert-opcode, require, eth-call

I have a smart contract with required message and pretend to use the required/validation message in front end.

```
require(bytes(hashAlreadyRegistered[hash]).length  == 0, "Hash already registered");
```

I'm trying to get the reason of revert using `web3.eth.call`.

By my understanding reading the [doc](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.9/web3-eth.html#call) if i pass the object generated by `sendTransaction` it will work. I think it is what i'm trying to do but didn't work so far.

**My codes**

`sendTransaction` method:

```
await canManipuleContract.methods.setDocumentHash('#_' + request.body.hash)
    .send({
      from: fromAddress,
      gas: 400000,
      gasPrice: 21000000000
    })
    .then(function(txRaw) {
      console.log(txRaw)
      return response.json( txRaw.transactionHash );
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      handleRevert(error);
      console.log("Error: \n" + error);
      return response.json( 'error' )
    })
  }
```

`web3.eth.call` method:

```
function handleRevert( transactionObject ) {
    web3.eth.call( transactionObject, function( err, result ) {
      if ( ! err ) {
        console.log( 'result ' + result )
      }
      console.log( 'err ' +  err)
      //return response.json( 'Error: Returned error: execution reverted' )
    })
  }
```

The return value of `handleRevert` is always `err 0x`. In geth console i clearly see the value `err` and `errdata` returning the correct messages.

If i pass the `contract address` instead `transactionObject` in `web3.eth.call` method it always return `Error: Returned error: execution reverted`, but never the required message it self.

**Version:**

Geth: 1.9.15-stable

web3.js: ^1.2.8

What am i missing here? Any others methods to get the message required of smart contract will help here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this,

```js
async function getRevertReason(txHash){

  const tx = await web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash)

  var result = await web3.eth.call(tx, tx.blockNumber)

  result = result.startsWith('0x') ? result : `0x${result}`

  if (result && result.substr(138)) {

    const reason = web3.utils.toAscii(result.substr(138))
    console.log('Revert reason:', reason)
    return reason

  } else {

    console.log('Cannot get reason - No return value')

  }

}
```

Comment: Oh yes, it works. But i'm not been able to get the `txHash` of the `var error` of `catch block` to pass into `getRevertReason` function. With e.g. `console.log( "Error: \n" + errorTransaction )` it prints the entire object of reverted transaction. If i for example `console.log( "Error: \n" + errorTransaction.transactionHash )` or any other property it throws `undefined`. any tip here?

Comment: i already tried to transform the object `error` to `json` and then `parse` or `split` it, but didn't sucessed.

Comment: also tried to change the `send` method to use `callback` but `error callback` always return `null` instead the reverted transaction.

Comment: remove await or write code inside try, catch block

Answer (score 7):

Web3 supports revert strings now: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.8/web3-eth.html#handlerevert.

You can activate it easily by setting `web3.eth.handleRevert = true`. Now when you use call or send functions, precisely one of the following:

- `web3.eth.call()`
- `web3.eth.sendTransaction()`
- `contract.methods.myMethod(…).send(…)`
- `contract.methods.myMethod(…).call(…)`

you will see a new message like

```
Error: Your request got reverted with the following reason string: This is the revert reason!
```

Comment: didn't work. I put `web3.eth.handleRevert = true` after beside the provider. e.g.                                                                                        
`const canManipuleContract = createContract(contractAddress),
 web3.eth.handleRevert = true;`

Comment: @RAFAELDASILVA It seems there is a Web3 bug for geth 1.9.5. It's already fixed: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/pull/3571 but you'll have to wait for the next Web3 version to be released.

Comment: this unfortunately doesn't work. "invalid arrayify value'"

Answer (score 1):

There is a `handleRevert` property in web3 itself.
For me, it only works when I set `web3.handleRevert = true` instead of the documented option, `web3.eth.handleRevert = true`.
The error message comes back in the `reason` attribute of the Error object that is thrown by the `send()` call of a smart contract method.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this.
Basically different RPC's will have different error response data. So you'll have to check the response and then simply use parseError on contract's interface.

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/142364/128523