# Can revert context be provided to frontend application for solidity's reverts?

Tags: solidity, dapps, ethers.js, require, custom-errors

There is solidity code that fails here:

```
error InvalidCheck(uint32 _check);

modifier someCheck(uint32 _check) {
  if (check != _check) revert InvalidCheck(check);
  _;
}
```

My frontend application fails on this check and doesn't provide any context about the error.

> "message: 'cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may r…UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT"

When my contract fails due to it being paused:

```
require(!paused(), "Pausable: paused");
```

This provides the "Pausable: paused:" message to my frontend.

Is using **require** the solution if I want to display error context to the frontend?

Comment: What version of ethers js are you using and the backend/node? Can you also pls post the entire error? If using geth, it includes the error data in the response and ethers js parses it under `error.error`, can you once check?

Answer (score 1):

Require and revert are both fine, but what you can do is a [callStatic](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/contract/contract/#contract-callStatic) (previously 'staticCall') to try the transaction and then handle the error however you'd like.

```
contract.transfer(someAddress, someValue).then((tx) => {
    return tx.wait().then((receipt) => {
        // This is entered if the transaction receipt indicates success
        return true;
    }, (error) => {
        // This is entered if the status of the receipt is failure
        return error.callStatic().then((error) => {
            console.log("Error", error);
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `parseError` method from your contract's interface. Read the docs for better understanding about [Interface parsing](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/abi/interface/#Interface--parsing)

Using your contract's interface, you can use the `parseError` method and pass it the error's data. In the following example, the data is found in `error.data.data` but this can be different on different RPCs as stated in this comment on github: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/discussions/3027#discussioncomment-4233143. Although I have no experience with Avalanche tho, so don't take my word for it.

Here's how you can do it:

```js
try {
  await myContract.someMethod();
} catch (error) {
  const revertData = error.data.data;
  const decodedError = myContract.interface.parseError(revertData);
  console.log(`Transaction failed: ${decodedError.name}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Revert undoes all state changes made during the current call, including any state changes made by called functions. It also provides a means for the calling function to determine the reason for the revert.

Require only undoes the state changes made in the current function and does not provide a way to communicate the reason for the failure.

Your usage will depend on requirements. Here is how I would handle it:

```
try {
  // call contract function that may throw an error
  await contract.someFunction();
} catch (error) {
  // check if the error is an InvalidCheck error
  if (error.message.includes("InvalidCheck")) {
    // display the error message to the user 
console.log(error.message);
  } else {
// handle other errors
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets test it.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


contract Test {
    uint32 check;
    error InvalidCheck(uint32 _check);
    error StringError(string why);

    modifier someCheck(uint32 _check) {
        if (check != _check) revert InvalidCheck(check);
        _;
    }
    function revertDirect() public {
        revert("revertDirect");
    }
    function stringError() public {
        revert StringError("it's string error");
    }
    function revertIt(uint32 _check) someCheck(_check) public {
    }
    function requireIt() public {
        revert("it's required");
    }
}
```

Result:
revert with `InvalidCheck`:reason: 'execution reverted: . Innermost error is at 0xbe45…c3d2: Vm reverted. .'

`require`: reason: "execution reverted: : it's required. Innermost error is at 0xbe45…c3d2: Vm reverted. it's required."

revert with `StringError`: reason: 'execution reverted: . Innermost error is at 0xbe45…c3d2: Vm reverted. .'

revertDirect: reason: 'execution reverted: : revertDirect. Innermost error is at 0xbe45…c3d2: Vm reverted. revertDirect.'

**Conclusion**:
Using revert(message) or require(condition, message) could expose reason, using revert(Customer Error) could not.